# how to change UIAlertController cornerRadius

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have created an UIAlertController like this:

```
    UIAlertController deleteView = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    deleteView.view.layer.cornerRadius = 100;
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"delete" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [cancelAction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSTextAlignmentLeft] forKey:@"titleTextAlignment"];
    [cancelAction setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:@"titleTextColor"];
```

I want to change the cornerRadius of action label.

[image]

I try to get the label like this:

```
  UIView *v1 = deleteView.view.subviews[0];
            UIView *v2 = v1.subviews[0];
            UIView *v3 = v2.subviews[0];
    UIView *v4 = v3.subviews[1].subviews[0].subviews[0];
            NSArray *arr = v5.subviews;
    NSArray *arr = v4.subviews;
    NSLog(@"v4:%@,arr:%@",v4,arr);
```

I'm getting an empty array

[image]

Comment: UIAlertAction is a component constructed by Apple, so anything inside it are private. You shouldn't be meddling with them. While you can, but there is not telling how Apple will change it in the future and your meddling could break when Apple does that. My suggestion is for you to use custom dialog boxes.

Answer (score 4):

You must set **masksToBounds** to yes

```
  deleteView.view.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
  deleteView.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: It works when cornerRadius more than 10.
I want to make the cornerRadius less ,but it doesn't work.

Comment: if that work for 10, then it works for numbers less than 10 too, only difference is you cant see the change. Hope your problem is solved

Comment: Thank you. The difference between cornerRadius is 3 and cornerRadius is 10 is obvious when I use a label.

Comment: you are welcome, if the answer helped you, please upvote or accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Following Sathya Baman's answer, add the following line. The background color must match the alertView's current background.

```
alert.view.backgroundColor = .white
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy , just do 2 line of code..

deleteView.view.layer.cornerRadius = 100;
  deleteView.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Comment: It works when cornerRadius more than 10.
I want to make the cornerRadius less ,but it doesn't work.